# How to export column names and labels as 1st and 2nd rows in spreadsheet [using R]?

Tags: r

Is there a way to export both the column name and label from R so that they appear as the 1st and 2nd row of a spreadsheet. I'm able to do the reverse (import) where I read in each row and then use names() and label() to assign the name/label. But I'm stuck on how to do the export without manually adding the labels as a row of data in R first.

[Column name/label in Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGdYl.png)

Comment: Which code did you use to attribute the labels (or import the data with them)?

Comment: I read in each row separately as a 1 row data frame. And then I used names() and Hmisc::label(), respectively, to assign these as the names and labels to the data set of interest (which was read in separately):

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
library(dplyr) #for pipes and mutate_if
library(purrr) #for map_chr
library(expss) #for apply_labels and labels management
iris2=iris %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
  apply_labels(Sepal.Length="length", Sepal.Width="witdh", Petal.Length="length2", Petal.Width="width2", Species="spec")

library(Hmisc)
rtn=rbind(names(iris2), label(iris2), iris2)
rtn %>% head
```

You have to use `mutate_if` to change all factors to character vectors, like I did in my dummy dataset, else you would have `NA` instead of names and labels.

Still, please note that this leads to untidy data as the first non-heading row is not an observation. It may be OK for outputting though.